# Float columns make them same in height (100%)

Tags: html, css

So, we have 3 floated columns.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A9dqD/

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#a {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
#b {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#c {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is column A to be as long (height) as column C. (So I can match backgrounds).

As you can see I cannot make column **a** take 100% (height) of the screen. Body gets 100% (height) of the viewport but not of the whole document, so column **a** is as long in height as viewport.

Here is the real life example: http://mac.idev.ge:800/wp1/

I don't want to use jquery to set height manually. I believe there is simple css trick to do this... and I need your help to find it :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the *faux-column technique* if your design allows it or if you need IE8 support, `display: table-cell` on 2 columns (you'd have to create a parent div to #b and #c)

Comment: @FelipeAls Faux-column cannot be done on % width based layout, right?

Comment: With 50%-50% columns, this should work: `background-position: center top;`. Not sure about (X%, 100-X%) columns as background-position other than 0, 50 (center) or 100% positions "*the point X% across the image with the point X% across the element*" but I think it's exactly what is needed

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want `#a` to have 100% height, and `#b` to be exactly 100px, you can do the following for `#c`:

```
#c { height: calc(100% - 100px); }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9dqD/1/)

PS: Not all browsers support `calc()`, so you should set a fallback height value BEFORE using `calc()`.

Comment: I meant height. It's 2:30am here and I'm sleepy. I edited the answer.

Comment: It works because `calc()` does the math for you. Instead of having to put a specific value for `#c`'s height, you can use the `calc()` function to calculate the correct result of the viewport height - 100px.

Comment: Awesome! But I cannot apply it to my real world example :S

Comment: Don't forget to set `float:left` for `#container`

Comment: Ok, I added everything to my example, page but it looks worth now :)

Comment: Add `min-height: 100%;` to `#sidebar`'s style.

Comment: Close inspector it still is less than column c :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage for your col b instead of pixels. col b is 20% and col c is 80% then it will match the 100% of col a.If col b doesn't have to be 100px exactly.
With the cal() here is a page with browsers that will support it:http://caniuse.com/calc